# AsyncTask never finished, onPostExecute never called, getstatus always returns running

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I work with androïd for some weeks only.
I'm trying to work with AsyncTask.
The problem is that my onPostExecute is never called and the AsyncTask seems to never finish.

I'm just getting this in log file:

```
04-04 11:47:42.722: D/BbHelper(10343): AsyncClic PreExecute ! 
04-04 11:47:42.742: D/BbHelper(10343): AsyncClic
04-04 11:47:43.774: D/BbHelper(10343): Waiting... clic=RUNNING 
04-04 11:47:44.838: D/BbHelper(10343): Waiting... clic=RUNNING 
04-04 11:47:45.869: D/BbHelper(10343): Waiting... clic=RUNNING 
04-04 11:47:46.919: D/BbHelper(10343): Waiting... clic=RUNNING 
04-04 11:47:47.977: D/BbHelper(10343): Waiting... clic=RUNNING 
04-04 11:47:48.999: D/BbHelper(10343): Waiting... clic=RUNNING 
04-04 11:47:50.001: D/BbHelper(10343): Waiting... clic=RUNNING 
04-04 11:47:51.005: D/BbHelper(10343): Waiting... clic=RUNNING 
...
```

undefinitly. So the getStatus always returns RUNNING.

So the AsyncTask is launched, but never finishes.

What is wrong in my code ?

Thanks in advance.
André

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private AsyncClic clic;
    clic=new AsyncClic();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        layout = (LinearLayout) LinearLayout.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_main, null);
    setContentView(layout);
        bActiver = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.bActiver);
        bActiver.setOnClickListener(new bActiverListener());
    }
    private class AsyncClic extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>{
        public Integer err = -1;        
    @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d(TAG, "AsyncClic PreExecute ! ");      
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "AsyncClic PostExecute ! ");
    //progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "AsyncClic");
    return err;
    }
}

    class bActiverListener implements OnClickListener{          
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    clic.execute();
    while(!clic.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)){
        try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Waiting... clic=" + clic.getStatus());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AsyncTask is never finished because you don't give it the opportunity to even start.

When you call execute, the looped readies the scheduling of doInBackground. But you loop and sleep on the main thread, never returning from onClick, never giving the looper the chance to schedule doInBackground on a background thread..

you must return before doInBackground is scheduled on the background thread.

either that, or you already have 10 asynctasks stuck.

### edit

not quite, but same idea.

Comment: I added the sleep to not get thousands of lines in log file. But if I remove it, I get the same result...

Comment: And I don't understand when you write that the task in not started. Cause I get 04-04 11:47:42.722: D/BbHelper(10343): AsyncClic PreExecute ! 
04-04 11:47:42.742: D/BbHelper(10343): AsyncClic
04-04 11:47:43.774: D/BbHelper(10343): Waiting... clic=RUNNING

Comment: Ok. You mean AsyncTask will run only after the "clic event" is finished. Indeed, if I remove the code waiting for "getstatus!= RUNNING", my onPostExecute is fired. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

The reason onPostExecute() is never called is that you sleep the main thread and since onPostExecute() is on run on the main thread you are never allowing it to be executed.

This should work. I have also cleaned up the code a little:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private AsyncClic clic=new AsyncClic();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button bActiver = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bActiver);
    bActiver.setOnClickListener( new bActiverListener());
}

private class AsyncClic extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>{
    public Integer err = -1;        

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d(TAG, "AsyncClic PreExecute ! ");      
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "AsyncClic PostExecute ! ");
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "AsyncClic");
        return err;
    }
}

class bActiverListener implements OnClickListener {          

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clic.execute();
    }
}
}
```